# Can this for loop be vectorized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
data = np.arange(10)
n = len(data)    
np.asarray([np.sum((data[0:i]-np.mean(data[0:i]))**2) for i in range(1,n)])
```

Can this for loop be vectorized maybe by expanding dimensions and then collapsing it?

I got the hint from somewhere that I can replace

```
np.mean(data[0:i])
```

with

```
np.cumsum(data[0:n-1])/(np.arange(n-1)+1)
```

Comment: please share a sample of your data. Also, what is the value of `n`?

Comment: data is just a bunch of floats (no NaNs) and 'n' is length of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be vectorized by expanding dimensions as you suggested. I think the secret sauce is using [np.tril](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) to zero out terms in the progression before summing:

```py
# calculate means using cumsum
mean = np.cumsum(data) / np.arange(1, n+1)

# expand into 2 dimensions
mean_2d = np.repeat(mean, n).reshape(n, n)
data_2d = np.tile(data, n).reshape(n, n)

# zero out unneeded terms
diff_squared = np.tril((data_2d-mean_2d)**2)

# sum along rows
np.sum(diff_squared, axis=1)
```

Comment: @Alex I just checked the performance of each method. The vectorized way is only faster up to a certain number of data points. On my machine when `n > 900` your solution performs better.

Comment: I see the same thing at around n ~ 1200